# Get salesrule id from order id in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, sales-order, shopping-cart-price-rules

How to get salesrule id from order id,for example:

```
public function getSalesruleIdByOrderId($orderId){
   //???
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$order->getData('applied_rule_ids');
```

In this field stored all sales rules ids.

You can obtain the order object by id using the `Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface::get($id)` method.

Complete class:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © MageWorx. All rights reserved.
 * See LICENSE.txt for license details.
 */

namespace MageWorx\StackExchange\Model;


use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;

class ObtainSalesRulesByOrderId
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $orderRepository;

    /**
     * ObtainSalesRulesByOrderId constructor.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository
    ) {
        $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
    }

    /**
     * @param $id
     * @param bool $asArray
     * @return array|string|null
     */
    public function getSalesRulesByOrderId($id, $asArray = false)
    {
        try {
            /** @var \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface $order */
            $order = $this->orderRepository->get($id);
            $salesRulesIds = $order->getAppliedRuleIds();
            if ($asArray) {
                $salesRulesIds = explode(',', $salesRulesIds);
            }
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $exception) {
            return null;
        }

        return $salesRulesIds;
    }
}
```